# "Uncaught Error: InvalidCharacterError: DOM Exception 5" when AES256 encrypted and base64 encoded string is decoded on browser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64, aes

At first, by ruby (I am using Rails), I made **AES256** encrypted and **base64** encoded string on server-side.

```
require 'aes'

# encrypt with AES256 and encode with base64
base64 = AES.encrypt("secret word", "pass")
```

Then, I want to **decode this on browser** with below libraries.

- Base64: https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64
- CryptoJS: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

My JavaScript code is below.

```
base64encoded = $('span.base64:first').text();
encrypted = Base64.decode(base64encoded); // <- bring Error!
secretWord = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "todo").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

The error is: `Uncaught Error: InvalidCharacterError: DOM Exception 5`

I suppose some invalid characters for browser were generated when encrypt on server-side. Please tell me how to avoid this error.

Comment: What do you get is you `console( base64encoded )` or `alert(  base64encoded )` - I can't see anything directly wrong in the Ruby, but I wonder if your template has messed with encoding

Comment: I am not doing with ruby, but i think your code snippet above base64 = AES.encrypt("secret word", "pass") is not base64 encoded, as I cannot see any base64 function call. The php snippet to this looks like base64_encode(AES::encrypt($value, $token, 256)); and is decoded by javascript with AES.decrypt(Base64.decode(content),token,256);